# Check if this profile exists in my database

Tags: php

I am trying to make a profiling using php. I don't know how to check. the only thing that it will check is the formno, firstname and lastname.

```
<?php
                        $FrmN = $_POST["formno"];
                        $FN = $_POST["firstname"];
                        $LN = $_POST["lastname"];

                        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                        if (!$con)
                          {
                          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                          }

                        mysql_select_db("vianney300", $con);

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO profile(FormNo, FirstName, LastName)
                        VALUES ('$FrmN', '$FN', '$LN')";

                        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
                          {
                          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                          }
                        echo "<br>1 record added!";
                        mysql_close($con);
                         ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set a unique constraint on a column or set of columns?  How to use a `SELECT` statement to read data?  What exactly is the issue?  Also, you'll want to read up on SQL Injection in PHP, because your code is ***highly vulnerable*** to attacks.  Users can delete your data, execute commands on your server, etc.

Comment: 1. just like David said you have to purify $_POST fields. 2. mysql_query is outdated, use mysqli or pdo instead. What so good about pdo is that pdo bind will handle it for you. 3. to answer your question, you can run a 'select' statement to check if FormNo exists

Comment: how to run a select statement? and where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<?php
    $FrmN = $_POST["formno"];
    $FrnN=$mysqli->real_escape_string($FrmN);
    $FN = $_POST["firstname"];
    $FN=$mysqli->real_escape_string($FN);
    $LN = $_POST["lastname"];
    $LN=$mysqli->real_escape_string($LN);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_select_db("vianney300", $con);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO profile(FormNo, FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES ('{$FrmN}', '{$FN}', '{$LN}')"";
    if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con))
    {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "<br>1 record added!";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: can you help me on how to check first if formno or firstname and lastname already exist before adding it.